# Extends Edittext class and add custom property to detect correct answer

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to design a class that extends Edittext such that

1)have new custom property named "realanswer" that contain string value

2)in this class after change focus, automatically(with out define listener in main activity) by a method in this class detect inputted value equal to "realanswer" or not!? if answer is true make textcolor green,else read.
this is my new class:

```
package com.faridi.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MFEditText extends EditText {
public Context mcontext;
public String realanswer;
public MFEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.mcontext=context;
    TypedArray typedArray = 
     context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.answer);
    String attr = 
     typedArray.getString(R.styleable.answer_answerAttribute);
    setCustomAttribute(attr);
    this.realanswer=attr;
    Toast.makeText(MFEditText.this.mcontext,
            attr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      typedArray.recycle();
      this.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
        count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, 
          int count) {        
       if(MFEditText.this.getText().toString().
        equals(MFEditText.this.realanswer)){
                MFEditText.this.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }else {
                MFEditText.this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            Toast.makeText(MFEditText.this.mcontext,
                    MFEditText.this.realanswer+
       "  "+MFEditText.this.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}
private void setCustomAttribute(String attr) {

    realanswer=attr;
}
private String getCustomAttribute() {

    return realanswer;
}
}
```

and this is my attr.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="answer">

    <attr name="answerAttribute" format="string"/>

</declare-styleable>


</resources>
```

and this is how i use it in my mainlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="25dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <com.faridi.myapplication.MFEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:answerAttribute="33"
    android:id="@+id/mfet"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

it work now. the problem is solved.

Comment: why dont you use textwatcher

Comment: I use it But i don't know why attr is null?!

Comment: where is R.styleable.answer_answerAttribute, this is null. This is not defined  in  your project

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984518/how-to-set-custom-edittextfield-properties-in-android     it is ok. i made a mistake in .obtainStyledAttributes.

Comment: thank u for your idea about textwatcher! type your comment as answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Done................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TextWatcher` on `EditText` to check whether the answer is realanswer or not like this

```
TextWatcher addremark_text_watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           // write your logic here

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

    };
```